# Animations that interact or overlook and are programmable for reminders via chat

Tags: animation, artificial-intelligence

This is an attempt to do something friendly, with potential pals, drawbacks, enhancement, and support.

Is it possible to AI talk to a graphic, like the Microsoft clipboard in Microsoft word, vita chat, to remind you to do stuff, eg. when you are doing certain things.

The phone understands what your are doing, and, based, on every you told it via its chat interface, it interacts with you in various ways.

Clip supporters and enhancers would also program clip behaviors to suit user needs and support them as the animations would get downloaded and associated vita a hash table with what their capability of telling you stuff was. Maybe, they could tell more. In any case, with each future version the animations get enhanced.

Having such a character could be supportive, and help with task guidance, light reminders, and overall direction streamlines for user actionability.

It is something that requires specific brain rhythms. Personally, I feel like I could crash with it, ... nevertheless, I think I could get glimpses of how it could feel good.

A fast brain can make a slower brain go faster, and then get somewhere in between bogged down and tired.

I can also think that psychiatrists always talk about blocking or freeing neurotransmitters, they never talk about neurotransmitter dynamics which may have cosine or exponential presence in availability.

But I say this just because I have taken medication, but I think people may just have different neurotransmitter factories and neurotransmitter production rates, which may modulate through time (in very normal and natural manners).

I am not an expert.

Anyways, looking from an abstract point of view, having a paperclip that can be programmed to remove your of stuff when you do specific things on the computer (or phone), may be a useful thing (it may even, have, if you wanted, a function of being an overlooking psychologist).